# How can I set $build['#cache']['max-age'] in the following code?

Tags: php, caching, drupal, drupal-8

In my drupal 8 custom module I use block to show the next and previous links of current article page. However, links do not change when switching nodes due to the caching. How can I limit the caching for this block?
I can't wrap my head around this.

```
  public function build() {
        /**
          * {@inheritdoc}
          */

          $node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');
          $created_time = $node->getCreatedTime();
          $nextprevlinks ="";
          $nextprevlinks .= $this->generateNext($created_time);
          $nextprevlinks .= $this->generatePrevious($created_time);

          return array('#markup' => $nextprevlinks);
        }
```

Comment: You literally just have to add the `['#cache']...` to the return array. That's it. You were so close it actually hurts to read. Also see [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202063/how-do-i-programmatically-set-cache-age). It's the same thing I said, but with extra options.

Comment: Someone has the same scenario of yours, you may be interested in the answer : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199527/how-do-i-correctly-setup-caching-for-my-custom-block-showing-content-depending-o

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else brain farts like I just did.

This is how my return now looks:

```
  return array('#markup' => $nextprevlinks,
              '#cache' => array("max-age" => 0),
          );
```